# How to pass image bytes to .Net byte[] with Soap?

Tags: c#, .net, python-3.x

I solved the problem.
base64.b64encode(response.content).decode('UTF-8')

The problem was just decode.

=================================

I want to .Net SOAP API from Python.

the .net API parameter has **byte[]** type.

So I want to pass python image bytes to .net bytes[].

The different condition between below code is
Python get image bytes from url and .Net get it from a local File.

Here's my python code.

```
import requests
import suds
...
...
url =https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_025.jpg
response = requests.get(url)
img = response.content

attachments = self.client.factory.create('ns0:ArrayOfAttachment')
attachment = self.client.factory.create('ns0:Attachment')
attachment.Data = img
attachments.Attachment.append(attachment)
params['Attachments'] = attachments

self.client.service.Send(params)
```

And example of .net is

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] img = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(img, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.close();

Message msg = new Message();
msg.Attachments = new Attachment[]
{
    new Attachment { Data=img }
}

Send(msg);
```

It raised errors like deserialization error because of wrong base64 sequence of offset 0.

(sorry but the error messages are not English so I can't let you know)

It works well if send without 'bytes[]' type parameter..

How can I make correct image bytes to .net byte[] in python?

Or maybe the .net API codes are wrong?

Comment: The error message about Base64 suggests that you shouldn't send raw bytes, but the Base64 encoded verion of those bytes. Try that?

Comment: Hi Hans.Yes I already tried that but fail too. I just got similar error messages with above (the difference of the messages is just offset and character). I don't know what is a valid encoding.